# is there called method define message in jar

Tags: java, classpath, nosuchmethoderror

Do you know if there is called method define message in jar file? I find there is in my code. In my Code, a method called: `void a(1)` , I compile it with `void a(long b)` in another jar file, but when I run it, it use `void a(int b)`, then there is an Exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. I want somebody explain why and it's better explain with JVM knowledge. And have you even found this question?

Comment: What do you mean by *have you even found this question?*

Answer (score 0):

It will throw this exception because compiled class expects the method with that specific (the one you compiled with) signature present at runtime too, which is not in your case